# determine if os X app runs from local disk or external storage device

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, linux, macos

My efforts included using 'getmntinfo' to checkout if app path is in mount location, but i always get true result since "/" is also mounted as can be shown in mount output :

```
/dev/disk1 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
map -fstab on /Network/Servers (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
/dev/disk2s2 on /Volumes/LaCie (hfs, local, nodev, nosuid, journaled, noowners)
/dev/disk2s3 on /Volumes/LACIE SHARE (msdos, local, nodev, nosuid, noowners)
```

"/" is local mount and I want to distinguish it from external storage devices that plugged to my computer such as the LaCie remote disk.

here's my code, i should i modify it to detect external mounts only  :

```
int check_if_mount(char* path) {

    struct statfs* mounts;
    int num_mounts = getmntinfo(&mounts, MNT_WAIT);
    if (num_mounts < 0) {
       printf("no mounts at all \n");
       return 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num_mounts; i++) {
       if (strncmp(mounts[i].f_mntonname,
                   path,
                   strlen(mounts[i].f_mntonname))==0) {
           printf("%s is mount (equal to beginning of %s)!!! \n",path ,
                   mounts[i].f_mntonname);
           return 1;
       } else {
           printf("no mount - candidate = %s %s %lu \n",    
                  mounts[i].f_mntonname,path,strlen(mounts[i].f_mntonname));
       }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

notice that this is a c code, but if necessary, i wouldn't mind using objective-c solution.

thanks